# Logstash stops working suddenly

Tags: logstash, kibana, devops, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have downloaded the logstash, Kibana and Elastic search version 5.1.2. i was sucessfully able to run them with complete pipeline of logstash, elastic search and kibana.
Not sure what went wrong in my configuration though i never made any specific changes. And when i am trying to start the logstash it is giving me following error.
I used command to run on windows as
**logstash -f logstash-simple.conf**

*logstash-simple.conf is my conf file that has very basic stdin operation.
But with this command i am getting below exception all of sudden and it is being hard to understand the root cause of the failure.

*

```
NameError: missing class name (`org.apache.logging.log4j.Level')
  get_proxy_or_package_under_package at org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:54
                      method_missing at file:/D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/vendor/jruby/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/java_package_module_template.rb:14
                             Logging at D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/logging/logger.rb:6
                            LogStash at D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/logging/logger.rb:5
                              (root) at D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/logging/logger.rb:4
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                              (root) at D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/loggable.rb:1
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                              (root) at D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/util/loggable.rb:2
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                              (root) at D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:1
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                              (root) at D:/Case Study/ELK/tools/logstash-5.1.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:2
                             require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1040
                              (root) at D:\Case Study\ELK\tools\logstash-5.1.2\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:70*
```

*

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for it.

1. the parsing template is not available
2. Sometime Java crashes because of heap/memory issue. You should ideally be running it as daemon so that it respawns itself, if your daemon keeps on crashing then you should try changing the heap size.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried increasing the heap size of logstash; but still faced the same problem. I am a beginner to logstash and help would be appreciated